# Hedging bets on two independent events?

Tags: probability, expected-value, gambling

> Let us say that there are two independent events $A$ and $B$. Event $A$ occurs with probability $0.3$ and event $B$ occurs with probability $0.4$. You can bet on these events with odds of $3:1$ and $7:3$, respectively. 
>  You are given $\$10$ to bet on these two events once. How should you split your money?

---

Calculating out the expected values, I found that A gives you a better bang for your buck so to maximize EV, one should put all their money on A. However, within the context of the problem, I believe that one is expected to hedge their bets some as there is a 70% chance that they will lose everything if they go all in on A.

However, in the case of splitting your money, I am unsure of the best way to go about it as no matter how much you put into event B, you are lowering your expected value in exchange for less variance. Is there an optimal spread? Or is it just down to one's risk tolerance?

> Now let's say that you can bet on these two events as many times as you want. How does your strategy change?

In this case I think that one would use the Kelly Criterion to maximize the growth of their money. But is there any merit to splitting your bet? Or is it better to just keep betting on A according to the Kelly Criterion?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Without specifying an objective function it's hard to say more.  Generally one wants to have high expectation with low variance, so you need a blend.

Comment: What would a sample objective function look like?

Comment: It should be monotonically increasing because having more money is nicer.  It might be concave downwards because the benefit of having another $\$$x is reduced the more you have.   Unless otherwise specified we use expected value and you should bet all on A.

Comment: Ratio of expectation to standard deviation is fairly standard.

Comment: How did you work out that "A gives you better bang  for your buck"?  If you bet $\ \$1\ $ on A you will lose your $\ \$1\ $ with probability $\ 0.7\ $ or win $\ \$3\ $ with probability $\ 0.3\ $, for an expected return of
$$
0.3\times3-0.7\times1=0.2
$$
dollars.  On the other hand, if you bet $\ \$1\ $ on B you will lose your $\ \$1\ $ with probability $\ 0.6\ $ or win $\ \$\frac{7}{3}\ $ with probability $\ 0.4\ $, for an expected return of
$$
0.4\times\frac{7}{3}-0.6\times1=\frac{1}{3}
$$
dollars, which is greater than the expected return  from betting on A.